# vcpkg Unable to compile grpc's specified version

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, vcpkg

Due to the needs of the project，need to use vcpkg to install 1.18grpc and 3.6.1.3protobuf，so I modified vcpkg-master\ports\rpc\CONTROL to the specified version，Of course, I also modified the CONTROL of protobuf.Finally vcpkg reported error: Error: Building package grpc: x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED

```
windows10 ,the latest version of vcpkg-master.zip

Building package grpc[core]:x86-windows...
-- Note: grpc only supports static library linkage. Building static library.
-- Using cached D:/Google/vcpkg-master/downloads/grpc-grpc-75475f090875e737ad6909a6057c59577f0c79b1.tar.gz
-- Extracting source D:/Google/vcpkg-master/downloads/grpc-grpc-75475f090875e737ad6909a6057c59577f0c79b1.tar.gz
-- Applying patch 00001-fix-uwp.patch
-- Applying patch 00002-static-linking-in-linux.patch
-- Applying patch 00003-undef-base64-macro.patch
-- Applying patch 00004-link-gdi32-on-windows.patch
-- Using source at D:/Google/vcpkg-master/buildtrees/grpc/src/577f0c79b1-086c8c6e6c
-- Configuring x86-windows
-- Building x86-windows-dbg
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:136 (message):
    Command failed: D:/Google/vcpkg-master/downloads/tools/cmake-3.14.0-windows/cmake-3.14.0-win32-x86/bin/cmake.exe --build . --config Debug --target install -- -v
    Working Directory: D:/Google/vcpkg-master/buildtrees/grpc/x86-windows-dbg
    See logs for more information:
      D:\Google\vcpkg-master\buildtrees\grpc\install-x86-windows-dbg-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_build_cmake.cmake:96 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_install_cmake.cmake:24 (vcpkg_build_cmake)
  ports/grpc/portfile.cmake:73 (vcpkg_install_cmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:73 (include)


I hope that vcpkg can install the specified version of protobuf and grpc, but the actual vcpkg only installed protobuf, and grpc failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue about your problem in [#8710](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/8710), I think it can work for you:

It seems the function is getting duplicate with system function.
Can you unzip this [patch](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/files/3766169/fix-duplicate-gettid.zip) , move it to **VCPKG_PATH/ports/grpc/** and add line:
**fix-duplicate-gettid.patch**
to **VCPKG_PATH/ports/grpc/portfile.cmake** line 27
then try to rebuild grpc?